# resize my app on another iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

Iv'e made an app for for iPhone 5, now i want to make it available for another iOS devices, but i don't know how to resize the label in different sizes.

I've got a label that change his point by the iPhone 5 size:

```
    if (a == true) {
self.minutes.frame = CGRectMake(271, 109, 140,100)
}
```

I used to play with the auto layouts but the label always "jumps" to here:

```
CGRectMake(271, 109, 140,100)
```

and back to his first place.

How can i fix it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for the different iphone sizes

```
if(  UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 568)

{self.minutes.frame = CGRectMake(271, 109, 140,100)}

else if(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 667 )

{ change to the size that looks best in iphone 6 }

else if(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 736 )

{ change to the size that looks best on iphone 6 plus }

else

{ change to the size that you want for the smaller devices }
```

Comment: And how do I do it  for iPhone 4s/6/6plus/ipad?

Comment: as for the ipad you may have to make a new storyboard, are you using xcode?

Comment: Yes, I am using xCode. But I prefer to know how to make it on the iPhones sizes. btw, I didn't understand your code, can you fix/explain it please?

Comment: for sure, are you trying to make the whole app on all devices? or just resize the label?

Comment: I'm trying to make the app on all the devices

Comment: Oh ok well auto constraints are what you will have to work with http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 the code i was showing you was to change just the label

Comment: Got it, but if I want to change the label only (like in your main answer) what do I need to write in Xcode? because i copy-pasted your main answer and it has error - there is no thing "IS_IPHONE_5"

Comment: The code hasn't error but for some reason it doesn't work when I run it on the simulator

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using AutoLayout for this, if you tried you need to make sure you edit the constraints to change the position or size of views instead of setting the `frame`.
Here is a good tutorial that introduces AutoLayout: http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Also, `UILabel` has an intrinsic content size (the size depends on the text and font), therefore you shouldn't be changing it's size manually.

Comment: How Can I change the size of views by auto layouts in this code:
 `if (a == true) {
//change position
}`

Comment: You could setup width and height `NSLayoutConstraint`s and then change the `constant` property on the constraint to edit the width or height. 

However, if you just want the view to position and size itself correctly depending on the device you shouldn't need to change the constraints programatically if you set it up correctly. Have you tried creating `NSLayoutConstraint`s in the Interface Builder?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do I do it?

Comment: Have a look at the link in my answer, it covers the basics on how to use AutoLayout in IB.

Comment: I saw the link and i know how to basically use the AutoLayouts but it doesn't answer my question - what happen when my boolean is true and the label has to move to another place..

Comment: Did you add the label in IB? There could be constraints that you added in accidentally which would cause the label not to move... Also, if you are changing the position of the label like that you should set the `origin` property on the frame and use `label.sizeToFit` to size the label correctly.